# Problem ignoring in a view the images inside the .views field body and the minimum number of characters?

Tags: 7, views

I need to remove the images appears in the view in the field body. I have tried the following code.

```
.view-mydisplay .views-field-body {
    display:none;
}
```

However, I cannot see the image but the "maximum length of characters" of my field-body are not showing completely. If I remove the image manually in the body, then the characteres are complete in the view.   Seems how if the image were counted like character.

For example if I have 300 max. characters in my view and I put an image only are showed 100 characters, after remove the images with css.  If I don't put the image in my body, the view shows the 300 characters configured in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Smart trim module](https://drupal.org/project/smart_trim) might be helpful. You'll be able to trim units by words or characters on stripped HTML.

> After installing and enabling Smart Trim, you should see a "Smart
>   trimmed" option in the format dropdown for your text fields. With
>   smart trim, you have control over:
>
> 1. The trim length
> 2. Whether the trim length is measured in characters or words
> 3. Appending an optional suffix at the trim point
> 4. Displaying an optional "More" link immediately after the trimmed text
> 5. Stripping out HTML tags from the field

Comment: Hi, Thanks very much for your option.  I don't want to affect the body of the node, only the view, I want if in the body of the node I put an image, this image not be showed in my view, however, when I remove the image with css the characters showed in my view are changed. For example if I have 300 max. characters in my view and I put an image only are showed 100 characters, after remove the images with css.  Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: This module is integrated with Views. Please install this module and edit your view field which you're going to trim. Select formatter `Smart trimmed`. Trim units `characters`. Check `strip html`. All should work without any additional css settings.